# How to use a shrinkDBs.bat file to truncate all log.ldf files in nested folders?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I would like to be able to shrink all log files in nested folders. I have used this same script to modify databases but I am having problems with the shrink command.

When I run this script, I get an error stating it can not find the database in the sys.database_files. So I'm guessing my database is going by a different name in sys.database_files or simply is not added. Can you help?

```
for /r /d %%i in (*) do (
ECHO  %%i\MY_DB.mdf
osql -S LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS -U johan -P johan_j-d master -Q "EXEC sp_attach_db 'MY_DB', '%%i\MY_DB.mdf', '%%i\MY_DB_log.ldf';"
osql -S LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS -U johan -P johan_j -d MY_DB -Q "DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'MY_DB_log',0,TRUNCATEONLY);"
osql -S LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS -U johan -P johan_j -d master -Q "EXEC sp_detach_db 'MY_DB';"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I should have been using the logical file name not the physical file name.